# Nested ng-binding with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, nested

I have some html that has data binded that needs to be dynamic, here is an example of the type of thing I'm looking for.

Basically I want to be able to get the `user.female.firstName`, or `user.male.firstName` but I wont know what the gender is until I run another function.

```
<h1>{{user.{{gender}}.firstName}}</h1>
```

Also how would gender look?

```
$scope.gender = 'female';
$scope.gender = female;
```

is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the HTML it would suffice:

```
<h1>{{user[gender].firstName}}</h1>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$scope.gender = 'female';
```

Here's a JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zftLR